# Backports for Candela Tech's kernel, OpenWRT

Tags: kernel, cross-compiling, openwrt

I have router with Archer C7 version of OpenWRT. My goal is to modify kernel to make ibss mode possible on 5GHz bandwith. Basically it is impossible, but I read that if I change kernel from current (3.18) to patched by Candela Tech (3.17) I will be able to install ath10k firmware, which will make my task possible. I am total newbie in those things and actually I don't really know what I should do. I have read many topics on the internet, but none of them helped me enough.

And now what I have done as far:

1. Downloaded 3.17 kernel from Candela Tech website.
2. Downloaded the latest backports from some other website.
3. Also obtained adequate OpenWRT SDK (15.05).

In Kernel directory:

```
$ cp configs/ct-x64.cfg .config
$ make -j8 deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-ct
```

It made 5 packages, which only 3 of them were required. But the problem was that those packages were too big. So actually it was the end of my journey, because size of router's HDD wasn't big enough.

Before I found out, that to make my goal possible, my router needs patched kernel, I had tried to cross-compile backports with using SDK build-in kernel. In backports directory I executed:

```
$ make defconfig-ath10k
$ make menuconfig ----> here I disabled CFG80211 and MAC80211
$ make -j3

Those variables were ofc in one line in every above step
CROSS_COMPILE=~/Desktop/SDK/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc- 

KLIB_BUILD=~/kernel_directory 

KLIB=~/Desktop/ 

ARCH=mips  

STAGING_DIR=~/Desktop/SDK/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/

PATH=~/Desktop/SDK/staging_dir/toolchain-mips_34kc_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/bin:$PATH
```

But nothing happened. I thought that some package will appear in $KLIB and it will be possible to
    # opkg install 
but it didn't compile.

One of many errors:

```
 WARNING: Symbol version dump ./Module.symvers
       is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

CC [M]  /home/xxx/backports-4.2.6-1/compat/main.o
CC [M]  /home/xxx/backports-4.2.6-1/compat/backport-3.18.o
CC [M]  /home/xxx/backports-4.2.6-1/compat/backport-3.19.o
In file included from include/linux/spinlock.h:50:0,
             from include/linux/wait.h:8,
             from /home/xxx/backports-4.2.6-1/backport-include/linux/wait.h:3,
             from /home/xxx/backports-4.2.6-1/compat/backport-3.19.c:10:
include/linux/preempt.h:18:25: fatal error: asm/preempt.h: No such file or directory
#include <asm/preempt.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```